# Too many levels of symbolic links osx Lion

Tags: xcode, terminal, osx-lion

i'm try to install a libraries but when the make file try to attempt to `Developer` folder it appear message

```
Too many levels of symbolic links.
```

So i try:

```
Go home folder (cd /)
```

then i try:

```
bash-3.2# cd Developer
```

and this is the output:

```
bash: cd: Developer: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

what could be the problem? can you help me?

```
ls -l
```

says me

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 10 14 Mar 09:13 Developer -> /Developer
```

Comment: What does `ls -l` say about the symlink? Most likely, it points at itself.

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel        10 14 Mar 09:13 Developer -> /Developer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If go to:

```
cd /
```

and `ls -la` outputs:

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 10 14 Mar 09:13 Developer -> /Developer
```

That's a problem. `/Developer` should be a **folder**, **not a symlink** pointing to itself.

Find out where the original `/Developer` directory is and delete the symlink, so you can create one pointing to it. If you can't find it, consider reinstalling XCode.

Answer (score 22):

Use absolute paths when making symlinks:

Doesn't (always) work:

```
ln -s file ../new/path
```

Works (more often):

```
ln -s /full/path/to/old/place/ /full/path/to/new/place/
```

Comment: Just had to use this again today... Thanks me from a year ago!

Comment: This solution works for me. Just use the absolute path.